# Express.js How to upload files(img,audio) with Mongoose Schema

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, file-upload, express

After some advices from  vernak2539 where to look after solution. My example of using express.js with formidable and mongoose look like this

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var post = require('./models');
var formidable = require('formidable');
var util = require('util');
var fs   = require('fs-extra');


router.post('/upload', function (req, res){

    var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
    form.parse(req, function(err, fields, files) {
    res.writeHead(200, {'content-type': 'text/plain'});
    res.write('received upload:\n\n');
    res.end(util.inspect({fields: fields, files: files}));

    new post({title:fields.title, content:fields.content,
    image:files.image.name}).save(function (e, result) {
        console.log('new post saved', result)
      });
   });

    form.on('end', function(fields, files) {
    var temp_path = this.openedFiles[0].path;
    var file_name = this.openedFiles[0].name;
    var new_location = 'uploads/';
    fs.copy(temp_path, new_location + file_name, function(err) {
        if (err) {
            console.error(err);
        } else {
            console.log("success!")
        }
      });
   });
 });
```

So basically to use files, I save the name of the file in image field and set the static path to directory with updated files, so then it can be used as src to img.

Comment: could you store it as a base64 encoded string? or can you save the file, then save the path?

Comment: i trying to do the second, so i made  app.use(bodyParser({ uploadDir:'./uploads' })); , but could you explain how it works, i should specify my post route so it will save the file?

Comment: Okay, so bodyParser has options, but uploadDir isn't one. Checkout their github page for the options. I would checkout the first part of this (the "app.post('/upload'...." part). From there you could then integrate your mongoose store. http://tonyspiro.com/uploading-resizing-images-fly-node-js-express/ or http://tonyspiro.com/uploading-and-resizing-an-image-using-node-js/

Comment: Thanks to your advice where to look after solution, I solved the problem, i will update post, so maybe somebody else can use it